# socket timeout exception in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys, time
from socket import* 

argv = sys.argv
host = argv[1]
port = argv[2]
count = argv[3]

port = int(port)
count = int(count)
data = 'X'*count


clientsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
clientsocket.settimeout(1)

clientsocket.sendto(data.encode(),(host,port))
print("Sending data to "+host+", " + str(port)+": " + data)


try:
    dataEcho, address = clientsocket.recvfrom(count)

except timeout:
    print("timeout")
    print("Receive data from " + address[0] + ", " + str(address[1]) + ": " + dataEcho.decode())
clientsocket.close()
```

When I run this code I get this error message

```
C:\Users\neil1\Desktop>python client.py 127.0.0.1 8000 1
Sending data to 127.0.0.1, 8000: X
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 22, in <module>
    dataEcho, address = clientsocket.recvfrom(count)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

But If i replace `except timeout` to `except error` the code works just fine. And is this the right way to deal with socket timeouts? Is there a better way to handle socket timeouts? Thanks in advance for help